# Alpine - Docker: returned a non-zero code: 139

Tags: docker, debian, alpine-linux

I run the same Docker build on two machines:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Debian 9.7

Everything works fine in Ubuntu but this is the problem I have in Debian during the Docker build:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c php7 /installer.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer' returned a non-zero code: 139
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.14-alpine
...
...
RUN curl https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /installer.php
RUN php7 /installer.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
...
...
```

In Linux, the error code 139 indicates a segmentation fault. 
I have a memory of 15437156 kB on Debian (Docker version 18.06.2-ce) and 16147116 kB on Ubuntu (Docker version 18.05.0-ce).

Note: The problem happens during the build `docker build ..`.

Do you know how to fix this on Debian?

Comment: I suspect it isn't Alpine related. Are you able to recreate the problem with other images?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the issuse

The command '/bin/sh -c rpm -ivh jdk-8u172-linux-x64.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 139

then i switched to using the legacy hyper-V instead of the WSL 2 that is provided by the docker engine, then everything worked fine

Comment: This definitely helped me in the situation with Windows 10 bld 2004 as Docker host.
Worked in parallel CentOS6 & CentOS 7 docker image preparations.
CentOS7 worked like a charm, but CentOS6 didn't, before I tried this.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading some versions and started hitting a similar issue to you, googled and found your post here. I was getting:

```
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && php composer-setup.php && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
 ---> Running in e73735530b5d
All settings correct for using Composer
Segmentation fault
```

After some testing I found that using `FROM alpine:3.9` caused it to Seg fault every time, but downgrading my Alpine version to `FROM alpine:3.8` stopped it occurring.

Not sure why though, but looks like there's something broken in the latest version of Alpine as I also didn't get this issue in Debian, Debian Slim, or Ubuntu 18:04.